# Loading/Building and Running existing Phonegap code in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, cordova

We've created a small project in phonegap on the PC in a www folder. I have moved the files on to the Mac but I can't figure out how to load it into xcode to edit the HTML further and to build/run it in the emulator or on my device.

I've never used xcode before and don't really understand how projects fit and work. I've tried to follow the Adobe Phonegap instructions I can't work out how to open an existing www phongap folder and there's no 'new cordova project' in xocde when creating a project as it shows in the adobe instructions, despite installing node.js, cordova and phonegap as instructed in various instructions I've tried?

I have phongap installed and can create a helloworld app in the phonegap Gui but again, can't figure out how to load it into xcode to build/run? I'm obviously not understanding the how xcode fits in with phonegap etc. and once this falls in to place I'm sure I'll be cooking on gas. Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cordova platform add ios
```

and then

```
cordova build ios
```

Then you will find the Xcode project folder in your **YourApp/platforms/ios/YourApp.xcodeproj** within your project. Just import it with XCode.

But Cordova will automatically build your app and emulate it by just using:

```
cordova run ios
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I've been trying to make sense of the various documentation sites and nothing has really fallen into place :) Such a great help :)